# Error Decrypting Key in R using rsa_decrypt from openssl

Tags: r, openssl

I'm trying to create a JWT claim for Box in R by following these directions: https://developer.box.com/docs/construct-jwt-claim-manually

I've loaded the config file containing the publickey, privatekey, and passphrase. The second step requires decrypting the private key with the passphrase.

I'm using `openssl::rsa_decrypt(data = charToRaw(privateKey), password = passphrase)` to do this, but I'm getting this error: `Error: OpenSSL error in rsa_ossl_private_decrypt: data greater than mod len`

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with the `data = charToRaw(privateKey)` argument, but I'm not sure what?

Answer (score 0):

I found out I was using the wrong function.

`read_key(privateKey, password = passphrase)` is what I was looking for.